# Dividing column in R with both letter and numbers/Removing leading zeros of certain values

Tags: r, datatable, calculated-columns

I have two problems. I'm trying to remove leading zeros for any number that is larger than 100 using R.

```
Obs Phecode
1   008 
2   009
3   1000
4   0100
```

I want it to look like this

```
Obs Phecode
1   008 
2   009
3   1000
4   100
```

Also, is there a way to divide a column by a certain number even though some of the rows have letters in them? I also want to have leading zeroes if the value is less than 100, but only if there's not a letter in the beginning.

Original Table

```
Obs ICD
1   99561 
2   980
3   E440
4   V4489
```

Desired Table

```
Obs ICD
1   995.61 
2   009.8
3   E4.40
4   V44.89
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is certainly possible (with some elbow grease and regexes), but ... is this really the best way to approach your problem? I see this as perhaps one of: (1) changing IDs in an obscure way; (2) trying too hard to prevent splitting a composite field into two (or more) columns, while still trying to do math-opts on part of it; (3) fixing data-import problems, where the data should have read `"995.61"` and `"E4.40"` initially but the import process broke it.

Comment: A solution to you first problem is something like `sub('(0*)([1-9]..)', '\\2',c("008", "009", "1000", "0100"))` using Regex. But as @r2evans said, improving the data importing part can make things easier for you.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a number is greater than equal to 100, change it to numeric (`as.numeric(..)` removes leading 0's) else keep the value as it is.

```
df <- transform(df, Phecode = ifelse(as.numeric(Phecode) >= 100, 
                                as.numeric(Phecode), Phecode))

df
#  Obs Phecode
#1   1     008
#2   2     009
#3   3    1000
#4   4     100
```